# Удаление повтрных слов из файла

Tags: python, файлы

Как удалять повторные слова и цифры?

К примеру файл содержит

```
11111
11111
11111
11111
22222
33333
44444
44444
```

На выходе должно быть

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
```

Comment: а где в вашем коде вы удаляете повторные слова-цифры?

Comment: Да похоже я команды не те подобрал

Comment: Петя, первая версия вопроса была еще куда ни шло, но сейчас это просто кандидат на закрытие.

Comment: Удалять повторные слова очень просто - находим слово, если повторное, то удаляем его.

Answer (score 5):

Если порядок на выходе не важен, то:

```
with open("input.txt","r") as fn:
    output = set(map(str.rstrip,fn.readlines()))
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = []                       # Список неповторяющихся строк

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f: # Открываем файл на чтение
    for line in f:               # Считываем строку
        line = line.strip()      # Убираем \n из строки
        if not line in lines:    # Если строки нет с списке lines
            lines.append(line)   # То добавляем ее туда

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f: # Открываем файл на запись
    for line in lines:           # Каждую строку из списка lines
        f.write("%s\n" % line)   # Записываем в файл
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, самый простой метод - в лоб проверять, было ли уже такое:

```
f = open("file.txt", 'r')
out = []
for line in f:
    if line not in out:
        out.append(line)
```

Так у нас на выходе будет список без повторов, с которым потом можно делать что угодно, к примеру, объединить в строку:

```
''.join(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = list(set(text))
```

В начале содержимое загоняется в сет, там удаляются повторные элементы, затем обратно в лист. Потом можешь уже вывести сам лист, как тебе нужно.